# Printing a specific number of nucleotides

Tags: reference, vcf-vcard, maf

I have a vcf statistics for heterozygote and homozygote cases and I would like to find matches with my maf file. The issue is that the reference field in maf file is different and it exlcudes nucleotides in alternative states, e.g. if you have a ref CAA and alternative variant is CAAAAA, in maf file your ref would be AAA.

So I need a code to change the ref field and alt in my file with statistics (may be add separate columns ref2 and alt2)

Here is a snippet of my file:

CHR POS ID REF ALT chr11 71579744 rs71049992 A ACAGCAGCTGGACTGGGAGCAGCAGGACCTG (insertion case)

chr11 124880551 rs71859853 CCGGAGT C (deletion case)

I think I should first count numbers of nucleotides in column4 and 5. then if number in column 4 is greater than 5 (meaning deletion), then in my ref2 that position will start from the next nucleotide different from alternative one.

For insertion, I will have an alt site changed and skipped ref nucleotides

As a result, I would like to have this:

CHR POS ID REF ALT REF2 ALT2
chr11 71579744 rs71049992 A ACAGCAGCTGGACTGGGAGCAGCAGGACCTG A CAGCAGCTGGACTGGGAGCAGCAGGACCTG

chr11 124880551 rs71859853 CCGGAGT C CGGAGT C

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: You talk about a _maf file_, but the _snippet_ you show doesn't look like [MAF](https://docs.gdc.cancer.gov/Data/File_Formats/MAF_Format/).

Comment: Hi Armali, Yes, this is a snippet from vcf statistics. I want to find a match between this file and my maf

Comment: The shown _snippet_ looks strange - it seems to start with column headers _CHR POS ID REF ALT_, but then data follows in the same line; is the _file_ really (un)structured like that?

Comment: Sorry that should be rather two lines CHR POS ID REF ALT (new line) chr11 71579744 rs71049992 A ACAGCAGCTGGACTGGGAGCAGCAGGACCTG

Comment: @Armali To give a better example. Here is a snippet of my maf file:  AC215217.1      chr10   21198   21205   AAAAAAAA        -       5'Flank DEL     GRD01   AAA     rs200438810     NA                      MODIFIER       ENSG00000260370 upstream_gene_variant   .       2256.16 21194                   NA
AC215217.1      (new line) chr10   21199   21205   AAAAAAA -       5'Flank DEL     SAS05   AAAA    rs200438810     NA                      MODIFIER      E      NSG00000260370  ENST00000566940 upstream_gene_variant   .       2256.16 21194                   NA

Comment: And here is the statistics derived from the vcf file for the same position: chr10   21194   .       CAAAAAAAAAAA    CAAAA   3       0       14
chr10   21194   .       CAAAAAAAAAAA    CAAAAAAA        5       1       11
chr10   21194   .       CAAAAAAAAAAA    CAAA    3       3       11
chr10   21194   .       CAAAAAAAAAAA    CAAAAAA 3       2       12
chr10   21194   .       CAAAAAAAAAAA    CAAAAA  2       1       14
chr10   21194   .       CAAAAAAAAAAA    C       1       0       16

Comment: So as you can see, the ref and alt does not match since in the maf file in case of indel, the common part of nucleotides in ref and alt are missed. This is why I am not able to find a match.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have not the required domain knowledge to make sense of that. I may have been able to suggest a method to covert the snippet from the question to the desired result, but now in the _better example_ the _statistics_ has eight columns instead of five, and there's no desired result given, so I don't know what to do.

Comment: @Armali. Thank you for your kind reply! In the better example there are 8 columns, so that the issue is to somehow took only non-matching nucleotides from 4 and 5 colums and match those to the ref column in maf file

Comment: If there is a match then I should add column 6 from the vcf stats file to my maf file

Comment: If I apply the changes from the original example (as I understand them) to the better example, there would also be two additional columns _REF2 ALT2_ with the values AAAAAAA CAAAA, AAAA CAAAAAAA, AAAAAAAA CAAA, AAAAA CAAAAAA, AAAAAA CAAAAA and AAAAAAAAAAA C; is this what you'd like to have?

Comment: @Armali Yes, exactly! That would be the case for deletion. For insertion, my ALT2 column should contain non-matching nucleotides. I guess I should count first which column (4 or 5) has more nucleotides in my vcf stats file?

Comment: Yes; I suggested a solution with the `awk` tool below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think I should first count numbers of nucleotides in column4 and 5…

With `awk`, you can use the `length` function to *count numbers of nucleotides*:

```
awk 'NR==1 {print $0" REF2 ALT2"}       # assuming first line has column headers
     NR>1  {if (length($4)<length($5)) print $0, $4, gensub($4, "", 1, $5)
            else                       print $0, gensub($5, "", 1, $4), $5}' file
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Currently trying to understand the code as something does not work properly. 
awk 'NR==1 {print $0" REF2 ALT2"}  NR>1  {if (length($4)<length($5)) print $0, $4, gensub($4, "", 1, $5) else print $0, gensub($5, "", 1, $4), $5}' het_homo_bex_PGL | more  (new line)    
awk: cmd. line:1: NR==1 {print $0" REF2 ALT2"}  NR>1  {if (length($4)<length($5)) print $0, $4, gensub($4, "", 1, $5) else print $0, gensub($5, "", 1, $4), $5}
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                                                                     ^ syntax error

Comment: If the `else` isn't at the beginning of a line, a `;` must be put before it.

Comment: Just curious, could you please explain this part gensub($4, "", 1, $5)

Comment: [`gensub`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html)`($4, "", 1, $5)` substitutes the `1`st match of `$4` (column 4) in `$5` (column 5) with `""` (nothing, i. e. deletes the match); column 5 is not changed, but the modified string is returned by the function.

Comment: Armali, may I ask you to help with another issue.

Comment: I have two files and first, want to look at the column with variant type in one of the files. If it is DEL then look at the match between three columns in two files (Chromosome, position, Reference) and append new columns in the first file with AC and AF coming from the second file. If it is IND then ook at the match between three columns in two files (Chromosome, position, Alternative) and append new columns in the first file with AC and AF coming from the second file.

Comment: I wonder if awk will do the job easier, as I am failing to do that in R now

Comment: This comment thread is not a good place to discuss _another issue._ You could post a new question (better with a few sample lines from the _two files_ and sample desired output) and leave a link to the new question here; then I'd have a look.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69361764/match-between-the-columns?noredirect=1#comment122597067_69361764